# Lightbox+bootstrap gallery, thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i need to a solution.
Now i have product with main image and some other photos under it. 
If photos are more than 3, i need to show them like carousel, not like no in rows by 3.

Attaching img, to explain it more.

[image]

*4th,5th etc photo should be hidden in carousel.
*All images should popup if they are clicked.

Comment: Are you open to use any other carousel plugin?

Comment: I have to use what is in project now.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly do it with Bootstrap but you need to do a bit of workaround since it is not available out of the box.

Suppose this is your HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-7">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Workaround JavaScript :

```
 $('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
  else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

Working demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/6ouybst4/

Now help yourself and implement lightbox in it :-)